# Wordpress latest posts menu item

Tags: wordpress, menu, posts

I'm  trying to get Wordpress to give me a menu item to go to "latest posts." They come up on the frontpage, but once I navigate away, I want a menu item to get back there. It seems so obvious, but several hours later, the best I could do was create a custom menu with a link to "uncategorised" as a workaround. There MUST be a better way! And this way, I get a box saying "Archive of posts filed under the Uncategorized category. " Not wanted!

Comment: When you click on "View All" within the Pages Box on the side in your Menus Screen, is there a "Home : Home" Option?

Comment: If not, have you tried creating a Custom Link to your Front Page URL?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom page in your template directory (http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) with a custom query (check at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts or http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Create a page in your admin and select the template you created.

Add a link to this page in your menu and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, but this sounds a bit daunting, and beyond my skill. I'm sure most blogs I've seen do this automatically - click on "home" and you're back to the homepage with the most recent posts on it. What am I missing here? For somereason I can't set frontpage and posts page the same on settings>reading. I feel like giving up. Such a basic thing and a whole day wasted! Is the solution above the only one? I'm not sure I can get my head around it!

Comment: You can also edit the archive.php page template and change the content inside h1 tags (<h1>change content here</h1>). You will have a different title for your category page and won't find "Archive of posts filed under the Uncategorized category. ". That will do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/09/20/code-snippet-add-a-link-to-latest-post-to-wordpress-nav-menu/

It's a filter that will 'search and replace' placeholder anchors such as '#latestpost1' with the actual url of the latest post, and thus dynamically modify the menu before it's rendered.

I'm not sure how this is for SEO, but it's a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your posts a category name. Use something generic like "News", "Articles" or "Blogs". Then, choose the category with the name you picked from the menu page under categories. Add this category link to your menu. Rename the link whatever you wish - "Blog" - for example. And, viola - all your posts will appear when people click on that link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-latest-post-in-nav-menu/ works really well and code is open sourced here: https://github.com/hijiriworld/dynamic-latest-post-in-nav-menu

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

I took this guy's code: http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/09/20/code-snippet-add-a-link-to-latest-post-to-wordpress-nav-menu/

Basically what he wrote is for the menu item to link to the latest post, not posts (plural), so I just modified it and it's working:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    // Hook in early to modify the menu
    // This is before the CSS "selected" classes are calculated
    add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'replace_placeholder_nav_menu_item_with_latest_post', 10, 3 );
}

// Replaces a custom URL placeholder with the URL to the latest post
function replace_placeholder_nav_menu_item_with_latest_post( $items, $menu, $args ) {

    // Loop through the menu items looking for placeholder(s)
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

     // Is this the placeholder we're looking for?
        if (!strpos(($item->url), 'latestpost'))
            continue;
      //  if ( 'latestpost' != $item->url )
        //    continue;

        // Get the latest post
        $latestpost = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
        ) );

        if ( empty( $latestpost ) )
            continue;

        // Replace the placeholder with the real URL
        $new_link = $item->url;
        $new_link = substr($new_link, 0, strlen($new_link) - 12);
        $item->url = $new_link;
    }

    // Return the modified (or maybe unmodified) menu items array
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: viper's solution is great – but it shows the latest post no matter what category. i would like to link to the latest post of a certain category. how can i achieve this?